Am I going to fail PA inspection due to this rotor?
Apparently, one of my rotor was damaged due to a brake clip scraping on it.
My brakes still feel ok. No sound or vibration. Should still be thick enough, only got 15k miles or less with it. But, am I still going to fail inspection due to this damage on the edge?

